# How to activate Xcode's Emulator Spotlight

Tags: xcode, spotlight

After I activate the Xcode iOS emulator how can I open the Spotlight Search in the Menu so that I can see the application icon?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS7 **simulator**, you need to pull the home screen icons down to reveal the Spotlight search bar. On iOS6 simulator, you need to swipe right on the homescreen icons.

[image]